# How to parse information between {} on web page using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook, tags

I am scraping sports odds from a web page and, as seen below, my result from a find request. The `.get_text()` will display `-110` which is fine.

What if I wanted to get any of the numbers within the `{}`. How would I go about getting these values?

I purposely deleted the opening < and closing > from the first div statement down below in order for it to appear.

```
results = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'op-item spread-price'})

print(results)

div class="op-item spread-price" data-op-info='{"fullgame":"-110","firsthalf":"-121","secondhalf":"-115","firstquarter":"-109","secondquarter":"","thirdquarter":"","fourthquarter":""}' data-op-overprice='{"fullgame":"-110","firsthalf":"-109","secondhalf":"-122","firstquarter":"-103","secondquarter":"","thirdquarter":"","fourthquarter":""}'>-110</div
```

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHbRm.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Long story short - This should show what todo**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
html_doc = """<div class="op-item spread-price" data-op-info='{"fullgame":"-110","firsthalf":"-121","secondhalf":"-115","firstquarter":"-109","secondquarter":"","thirdquarter":"","fourthquarter":""}' data-op-overprice='{"fullgame":"-110","firsthalf":"-109","secondhalf":"-122","firstquarter":"-103","secondquarter":"","thirdquarter":"","fourthquarter":""}'>-110</div>"""

   
bs = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
data = bs.find('div')

print(data['data-op-info'])
print(data['data-op-overprice'])
```

**Based on your "provided" information**

```
print(result['data-op-info'])
print(result['data-op-overprice'])
```

**Based on your comment you can replace the printing by**

```
import json
for k,v in json.loads(result['data-op-info']).items():
    print(k,v)
```

Hope that helps, let us know

Comment: print(results['data-op-info'])
{"fullgame":"-110","firsthalf":"-121","secondhalf":"-115","firstquarter":"-109","secondquarter":"","thirdquarter":"","fourthquarter":""}

print(results['data-op-overprice'])
{"fullgame":"-110","firsthalf":"-109","secondhalf":"-122","firstquarter":"-103","secondquarter":"","thirdquarter":"","fourthquarter":""}

This is what I get after using provided print statements
How do I get this info out of there 
Full Game   -110
First Half     -121
Second Half -115
First Quarter  -109
Second Quarter ""
Third Quarter ""
Fourth Quarter ""

Something like this

Comment: @Rick Sweeney - Take a look for the last part in my answer, that I appended

Comment: @RickSweeney There are a lot of ways, but i thing converting it in a dict and loop is a common one.

Comment: for k,v in json.loads(data['data-op-info']).items():
    print(k,v)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-d17e3fdb4b82> in <module>
----> 1 for k,v in json.loads(data['data-op-info']).items():
      2     print(k,v)

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: @RickSweeney imported json ? 

`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_doc = """<div class="op-item spread-price" data-op-info='{"fullgame":"-110","firsthalf":"-121","secondhalf":"-115","firstquarter":"-109","secondquarter":"","thirdquarter":"","fourthquarter":""}' data-op-overprice='{"fullgame":"-110","firsthalf":"-109","secondhalf":"-122","firstquarter":"-103","secondquarter":"","thirdquarter":"","fourthquarter":""}'>-110</div>"""
   
bs = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
data = bs.find('div')

import json
for k,v in json.loads(data['data-op-info']).items():
    print(k,v)`

Comment: Im sorry - my bad - that works GREAT - so now do i substitute the URL for the htmldoc = line

Comment: @RickSweeney No problem - So your issue is fixed and answer accepted? 
Can you provide an extract from the fixed code? It would be interesting for others too.

Comment: Yes that part is fixed - overall still trying to plug away as I did not ask the question properly as there is far more json that it needs to iterate through